# Is it possible to merge my storyboard and someone else's storyboard that I downloaded form GitHub?

Tags: ios, xcode

So Im pretty new at coding and so are these 2 other guys that I'm working with. One of them uploaded his part of the project to GitHub. So I downloaded his part and put all his files in my Xcode project(Not sure if that was the right thing to do). Im trying to figure out the method in which I merge his login storyboard and and mine storyboard into one? Again I'm super new at this.

Comment: Storyboard are essentially XML files, so if you right click on right Storyboard and choose Open as>Source code, in theory you could paste the parts you copied from another Storyboard file. However, I have never tried this, so I am not sure if it would actually work in practice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109998/how-to-collaborate-on-a-project-with-xcode-storyboards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and utilize sourcetree with a bithub account. Sourcetree is a great way to handle collaborating on a shared repository.